# DH parameters for a PPP arm

Tags: forward-kinematics, dh-parameters

I found this picture on the web and was working through it to make sure I understood the derivation for a PPP arm. I believe for link 2, alpha_2 ought to be -90 and not +90.

Additionally, I don't understand why theta_3 is -90, give that link_3 is only a translation of link_2.

Am I misunderstanding something or are the provided DH parameters incorrect with respect to the provided drawing?

[image]

Comment: where did you get that picture?

Comment: I was googling for 'dh parameters PPP arm' and found it under the image search result. Why do you ask?

Comment: i did not ask you `how did you find the picture?`  ......  i guess that  i should have said `please provide a link to the picture` ...... the reason that i ask is that there may have been a link to an explanation regarding the calculation

Comment: ah, apologies for misunderstanding. I found the picture here - https://www.reddit.com/r/robotics/comments/5fga3d/dh_parameter_check/. The link has some short discussion but doesn't seem to agree on an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DH parameters comes from the common normal between two consecutive Z axes. Every time you're in doubt about the DH parameters, you can follow common guidelines between two consecutive axes.

In this case, $d_i$ is the distance along previous Z starting from the previous origin O to the intersection of the new X and previous Z axis, which is variable in the case of prismatic joints.

$r_i$ (or $a_i$) is the distance in current X starting from current origin O to the intersection between previous Z and current X.

$\theta_i$ is the angle in previous Z to align the previous X with the new X.

$\alpha_i$ is the angle in current X to align previous Z to current Z.

From the picture, starting with link 1:

- $d$: The distance from previous O to the intersection of previous Z and current X is variable, so it's *d1*.
- $a$: The distance in current X starting from current O to the intersection between previous Z and current X is *0*.
- $\theta$: The angle in previous Z to align previous X with the new X is *0*.
- $\alpha$: The angle in current X to align previous Z to current Z is *-90* (right hand rule).

For link 2:

- $d$: The distance from previous O to the intersection of previous Z and current X is variable, so it's *d2*.
- $a$: The distance in current X starting from current O to the intersection between previous Z and current X is *0*.
- $\theta$: The angle in previous Z to align previous X with the new X is *90* (right hand rule).
- $\alpha$: The angle in current X to align previous Z to current Z is *-90* (right hand rule).

For link 3:

- $d$: The distance from previous O to the intersection of previous Z and current X is variable, so it's *d3*.
- $a$: The distance in current X starting from current O to the intersection between previous Z and current X is *0*.
- $\theta$: The angle in previous Z to align previous X with the new X is *0* (right hand rule).
- $\alpha$: The angle in current X to align previous Z to current Z is *0* (right hand rule).

So the correct DH Table for this robot would be:

---

Link 1:   $a=0$, $\alpha=-90$, $d=d1$, $\theta=0$

---

Link 2: $a=0$, $\alpha=-90$, $d=d2$, $\theta=90$

---

Link 3:  $a=0$, $\alpha=0$, $d=d3$, $\theta=0$

---

You can see some guidelines [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rA9tm0gTln8).

Comment: I did try to edit, but it was rejected.  You have an error in your final table of D-H parameters for link 1.  d should be **d1**, not d2 (as noted earlier in your answer).

Comment: thank you, this makes sense to me. Also, I believe you meant d1 for link 1 in your table at the bottom?

Comment: Yes, it's d1. I edited. Glad to help.